# PowerShell for removing service application association

Tags: service-application, service, managed

I have created a Managed metadata service application named MMD1.

It's associated with 2 web applications, say webapp1, webapp2. Now I am creating a new  MMD called MMD2. I would like to remove the MMD1 association with webapp1 and webapp2 and associate it with MMD2.

I am trying to do this with PowerShell. But I do not know what API to use.                              Help is appreciated.

```
$serviceapplicationname = "MMD1" 
$spapp = Get-SPServiceApplication -Name $serviceapplicationname 
$spguid = $sapp.id
$webapp1 = Get-SPWebApplication http://webapp1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, all Web applications are associated with the farm’s Default group of service application connections, although you can change this setting. You can also create one custom connection group for each Web application in the farm. You can change the service applications with which a Web application is associated at any time, and you can change the service applications that are included in the Default service application connection group.

Now you need to remove the MMD1 from the default group and Add the MMD2 in it.

```
Add -SPServiceApplicationProxyGroupMember [-Identity connGroup ] [-Member serviceapp ]

Remove-SPServiceApplicationProxyGroupMember [-Identity connGroup ] [-Member serviceapp ]
```

http://mysharepointwork.blogspot.com/2010/03/associate-service-application-with-web.html

You can also think about creating new custom group
[New-SPServiceApplicationProxyGroup](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607660.aspx)

Comment: That helped a lot. @Waqas, thanks for your time and reply.